# Automatically change default database path in MS Access?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, default

We recently switched servers and many times in the past it has not been an issue, but this time the My Documents folders had some issues on the server somehow, so everyone's getting an error prompt when they open a MS Access file ("cant change working directory").

Googling it, it appears to be due to the path listed in File -> Options -> General -> Default Database Folder.

Does every user have to change this themselves to their actual My Documents folder? Why isn't it linking automatically like it has in the past? Is there a way I can automate / change it for anyone who opens the database?

For instance if I know their current default path looks like `\\OLD_SERVER\tshome$\user_name\my documents` can I change it to `\\NEW_SERVER\tshome$\user_name\my documents` automatically?

Comment: Each install of Access will have to be changed. Have you used the same server name when changing hardware in the past? Did you use a new server name this time?

Comment: Alternative is to change registry key which is really more difficult.